# Normal map baking odd gray shapes

Tags: baking, normal-map

I am following a grant bait tutorial and am at the normal baking part but have encountered 2 problems. (1) certain parts of the mesh are baking completely grey (the first bake I did didn't cause the mesh to turn grey but I re-unwrapped and it turned grey) and (2) I have weird lines throughout the edged of my mesh. Any idea how to fix this?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, have you set your Normal Map node to non-color?

Comment: @moonboots It seems to have turned off at some point. that fixed the color distortion but not the lines around the edges. I could upload the file or more pictures of that would help

Comment: @moonboots my file is too big to paste there, is there another way to send it to you? I will try to upload more pictures in the mean time

Comment: @moonboots https://we.tl/t-Z6ksw0D6c6 here is the file

Comment: It looks like you didn't pack your image so I couldn't take a look at it but anyway I've created a new image (activated 32-Bit Float), baked, and everything's ok: zupimages.net/up/21/43/7u4o.jpg

Comment: @moonboots sorry I didn't pack, I don't know how to pack. What did you change to make it work? I am new to baking in blender because I ussually do it in substance painter

Comment: I haven't done anything else than what I say, I've created a new image with the 32-Bit Float option enabled. If it still doesn't work maybe try with another Blender version

Comment: @moonboots were you able remove the odd edge marks? It looks like you still have some of the odd edge marks in your image but its hard to tell

Comment: no, it seems to work fine, I can't tell why it's not the case for you  :/

Comment: @moonboots I used the newer version of blender and it worked fine, thank you so much for you patience and help. Have blessed day